# CodeIgniter How to access session variables in twig templates

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, variables, twig

somebody can help me please. I'm new in CodeIgniter and Twig. I have declared in my controller the following:

```
$datasession = array(
'nick' => $sess_nick,
'login_ok' => true
);

$this->session->set_userdata($datasession);

redirect('app'); //app is a controller that render the template view.
```

then, the question is: How can I get those variables from the twig template? I tried using:

```
{{ session.userdata.nick }}
```

but it shows like empty string.

thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0):

To add the session variable on your twig template, you have to add the following line in your Twig library or controller.

```
$datasession = array(
    'nick' => $sess_nick,
    'login_ok' => true
);
$this->session->set_userdata($datasession);
$this->_twig->addGlobal("session", $this->CI->session);
```

Then on your twig template, you can print the session like this

```
{{ session.userdata.nick }}
```

Since in CodeIgniter, the session stored by user is usually in the userdata array. Otherwise, you can just simply call the session variable and name

```
{{ session.nick }}
```

Src: http://llanalewis.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/codeigniter-add-session-in-twig.html

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method Twig::addGlobal() in C:\AppServ\www\curso\ApplicationCI\application\controllers\putocontrolador.php on line 151

Comment: I've checked my Twig.php file in libraries folder to realize that there's not such method called addGlobal. What can I do now?

Comment: Can you check if Twig is installed & being used correctly? Check this guide http://llanalewis.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/adding-template-engine-twig-on.html

Comment: P.S. Twig::addGlobal() method does exists. But I think you have to get an instance of it. Have a look at this also http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#globals

Comment: @Latheesan Do this work with CI 3, I have tried this but not showing up anything!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to Latheesan Kanes for your help. It was so much helpful your guideness. I want to share the way I solved this problem.

As Latheesan mentioned we have to use the addGlobal() method (I added this method in my Twig library folder)

like following:

```
$this->_twig->addGlobal("session", $this->CI->session);
```

But don't forget before to load the Session library. This way.

```
$this->CI->load->library('session');
```

This way you can have your session globally in all your twig views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CodeIgniter 3RC3 and the [Twig-Codeigniter library](https://github.com/bmatschullat/Twig-Codeigniter) (thanks Erik & Bennet!).

To enable easy session access in twig, I added one line to the /application/libraries/Twig.php file's __construct() method:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->_ci = & get_instance();
    $this->_ci->config->load(self::TWIG_CONFIG_FILE); // load config file

    // set include path for twig
    ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPPATH . 'third_party/Twig/lib/Twig');
    require_once (string)'Autoloader.php';

    // register autoloader
    Twig_Autoloader::register();
    log_message('debug', 'twig autoloader loaded');

    // init paths
    $this->template_dir = $this->_ci->config->item('template_dir');
    $this->cache_dir = $this->_ci->config->item('cache_dir');

    // load environment
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->template_dir, $this->cache_dir);
    $this->_twig_env = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
                                            'cache' => $this->cache_dir,
                                            'auto_reload' => TRUE));

    // ADD SESSION TO TWIG - JZ
    $this->_twig_env->addGlobal('session', $this->_ci->session);
    // SESSION IS NOW AVAILABLE IN TWIG TEMPLATES!

    $this->ci_function_init();

}
```

Now that we have our session loaded into our twig instance, we access session variables (such as CI's [userdata](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data)) in our twig templates like so:

```
<span>__ci_last_regenerate: {{ session.userdata.__ci_last_regenerate }}</span>
```

[php](/questions/tagged/php)[twig](/questions/tagged/twig)[codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter)

Comment: This works in the release version of CodeIgniter 3.0+ as well.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used session variables in Twig with this code:

**In controller:**

```
$datasession = array(
    'language' => "PHP",
    'framework' => "CodeIgniter"
);

$this->session->set_userdata($datasession);
$this->twig->addGlobal("session", $this->session);
```

**In template:**

```
{{ session.language }} 
{{ session.framework }}
```

I'm using https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-ss-twig